# Same Origin issue with web service call

Tags: c#, jquery, json, wcf, jsonp

My web server runs at `http://mypc.com:80` 
`

Given the following snip:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var myURL = "http://mypc.com:8000/PSOCharts/service/HighChart_ColumnChart/i";


    $.getJSON(myURL)
        .done(function(data) {alert(data);});

    });
```

I am running to this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mypc.com:8000/PSOCharts/service/HighChart_ColumnChart/i. Origin http://mypc.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I understand why (I think) b/c my webservice runs at port 8000 which is different from what IIS is running on (port 80).

I thought I could get around by using jsonp (according to the jQuery documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

So I copied the example of making a call to the flickr api, but it isnt working. Any thoughts/sugggestions?

**UPDATE**

Ok so my request is being made now:

```
var myURL = "http://192.168.1.104:8000/PSOCharts/service/HighChart_ColumnChart/i?jsoncallback=?";

    $.ajax({
        url :myURL,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {a(data)} ,
        error: function(){alert("err");},
        });
```

But I am continually hitting the error function, here is what's being returned:

```
[1.4,54.43,49.39,93.23]
```

Now I'm assuming this is b/c the response text doesnt contain any type of callback

here is the part of the interface I'm calling:

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "HighChart_ColumnChart/{id}?callback={cb}")]
    List<double> HighChart_ColumnChart(string id,string cb);
```

Here is the actual function being called:

```
  public List<double> HighChart_ColumnChart(string id,string cb)
    {
        var z = new List<double>();
        z.Add(1.4);
        z.Add(54.43);
        z.Add(49.39);
        z.Add(93.23);
        return z;
    }
```

when I debug, the CB param is something like : "jQuery19108121746340766549_1372630643878". 
How do I modify the code to wrap it correctly?
Thanks for the help thus far!

Comment: From your link: "If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details."  Maybe you need to add this?

Comment: The first answer from this will help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jsonp you must modify the response from the server to wrap your json data in a method as specified by the callback query string parameter.

So if your server was returning something like:

```
["test1", test2]
```

it would become:

```
callback(["test1", "test2"]);
```

Where "callback" is specified by jquery in the query string to your "webservice"

EDIT: Given your sample code, I think you will need to serialize and wrap your response manually. MVC has a Jsonp helper method, and I see reports that in .NET4 WCF will do it for you based on a callback parameter being present, but if that's not working then add something like the following to end of your method.

```
JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string jsonString = s.Serialize(z);

    return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(string.Format("{0}({1});", cb, jsonString), "application/json; charset=utf-8", Encoding.UTF8);
```

(modified from here: [Wiring up JSONP using JQuery and WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773355/wiring-up-jsonp-using-jquery-and-wcf))

Comment: I think you are on the right track now - but I'm unsure how to wrap it in the the correct 'callback' My code has been added.

Comment: that did it, genius. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use `jsonp`, make sure one of the following is the case:

- If you're using `$.get` and set `dataType` to `jsonp`.
- If you're using `$.getJSON` and included `callback=?` in the URL.